# Camera zoom level

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avcapturedevice

Is it possible to get the camera zoom level on various device models in iPhone like in built in camera programmatically example 0.5x, 1x, 2x etc?

I am unable to find the solution. Anyone can you please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a capture session and select the desired capture input, more details you can find here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/capture_setup/setting_up_a_capture_session

There is also a special document on how to choose a capture device: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/capture_setup/choosing_a_capture_device